# How do I suppress the boilerplate 'WASX7209I: Connected to process...' from the wsadmin command?

Tags: wsadmin

I have a wsadmin script that needs to produce a very specific output format that will be consumed by a third-party monitoring tool.  I've written my Jython script to produce the correct output except that wsadmin always seems to spit out this boilerplate at the beginning:

*WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node [node] using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager*

Is there a way to suppress this output or will I need to do some post processing to strip off this superfluous info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to suppress that output from being generated.  I think you're going to have to strip it out post execution if your consuming system can't handle it...

Comment: That is what I've done for now.  I have the output piped to sed to strip off the first line like this: wsadmin -lang jython -f myscript.py | sed '1d'

Comment: That should work.  I was thinking a '| grep -v WASX7209I' assuming you were running *nix, but sed works just as well!